# Azure Durable Function - Queue Instances of Orchestration for Single Instance ID

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a data layer that is created and updated from multiple input layers. We currently use functions and a Service Bus session to ensure that only a single worker is ever trying to update a data layer at a time, even if there are multiple input layers that need to be aggregated in the queue. We'd like to use a Durable Orchestration though, since the aggregation function is long running with multiple steps. Is there a way to ensure that a single orchestration is only ever running for a Data Layer ID, and the orchestration is still invoked for all pending Input Layers?

[image]

I've used an InstanceId, but calling `StartNew` with an instance ID that is already running errors (I was hoping it would queue).

I've thought of creating *eternal orchestrators* that loop and wait for external events, since external events queue. My understanding though is this would create an *eternal orchestrator* per Data Layer ID, which are significant.

I've also thought of a still using Service Bus sessions, and have the function that invokes the orchestrator and monitor its progress - but this would then keep a long running function active that is, technically, doing nothing - not sure how that would impact the runtime (would be pretty light weight in theory, just a sleep/check loop)?

I've also looked at durable entities to trigger the orchestrator, but I don't think there is a reliable way to block within the durable entity method and wait for the orchestration to complete - and it may be beyond the intended use case of the durable entity anyway since we wouldn't use it to store state, just for coordination.

Answer (score 0):

By setting maxConcurrentCalls and maxConcurrentSessions to 1 , you would achieve singleton processing and I think this would solve your problems as you need a single instance to update the data layer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings

Feel free to reach out to me if you have any queries or concerns.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! - my question is really vague I know - but it has more how to make the durable function orchestrator run as a singleton per instance ID _and_ queue subsequent calls for the same instance id.